# Doubt about the real need for R and C on micro-controller inputs

Tags: stm32, design, debounce

EDIT: as @Connor Wolf noted these are debouncing capacitors, sorry for the poor language

I am not an engineer, I am just an hobbyist who likes to learn and understand the reason of things.

I have had one year and an half of experience with arduino-style and other MCU.
Now i am design a development board for STM32F103RC just for "joke" to improve my abilities. I copied a lot of design especially from leaflab and olimex. For sure who is reading this question have more experience on the field than me, and i am looking for your suggestions.

So coming back to the original question i found on olimex (i can't post the link due to low reputation, see comments) this schematics for a general switch:

[image]

or from leaflab's maple rev5 this:

[image]

Now my ridiculous year and an half of experience says me that all these components are an exaggeration. I am used to wire a switch without any other component I just use the internal pull up/down of the MCU and I never had a single problem.

While we are here i have other doubts which answers I suspect are: "it is the same don't mind"

1. I know that pull-up res for the i2c depends mainly on the
   communication speed, i have always used 10k, could i continue to use
   them or should i use different values?
2. For the boot-pins olimex and leablab uses different values, 10k and
   100k, i hope it is the same
3. In the link above from olimex, they use a 1M res for the 8Mhz
   crystal (i saw this also in the arduino's boards) but they don't use
   it in the 32.768Hz crystal, could it cause problems?

I asked these question because I would like to have a few sugestion from people who made some boards and know what is really needed and what is a surplus. I know that a resistor/capacitor more won't destroy my finances, I am not trying to save money but time and space on the board since I will solder all my myself
I hope you will understand these silly questions...

Comment: link for the olimex board: https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/ST/STM32-H405/ and for leaflab: https://github.com/leaflabs/maple/blob/master/maple-r5/maple-r5-schematic.pdf

Answer (score 7):

I strongly suspect you're confusing the point of those resistors.

My money would be that a lot of it comes from trying to make the board robust under "boneheaded-user" situations.

The 1K resistor in both circuits is more to make it so if the connected IO pin is accidentally set as an output, it won't damage the microprocessor if the button is pressed. The capacitor in the first picture isn't /really/ needed, but it means you have to do less work in the MCU to handle switch bounce. The pullup resistor is similar, it means the switch functionality can be more easily understood without having to discuss the IO Buffer structure.

Most importantly, **that is not a decoupling capacitor**, so you do need decoupling capacitors, but you appear to not be asking about that.

---

To answer your questions:

1. The pull up resistance on an I2C bus is largely a function of bus capacitance, and for most I2C busses, there is a large range of values that will work. 10K should be fine for most small busses.
2. Again, these resistors are just to place the boot pins in a known state at power up. The choice for them is usually a matter of "what resistor values am I using elsewhere, so I don't need another BoM line". It's not critical.
3. You should set up the crystal as the STM32F103 datasheet specifies. Various eval boards may or may not be correct, and there's some latitude in the range of connections that may be functional. A 1MΩ resistor isn't going to have much effect except for ultra low power contexts, so it may only be needed if the MCU is in a ultra-low power sleep. The 32KHz oscillator may have completely different burden requirements. Again, [**read the datasheet**](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f405rg.pdf), not random eval boards.

   ST Have an [entire application note (AN2867)](http://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00221665.pdf) about how to set up their MCU oscillators.

Comment: yes, you are right i misunderstood the reason of these components and i am using the wrong technical names. Do you think it is a good possibility? https://s22.postimg.org/xgpae75lt/Immagine.jpg i am not using the 22k pull-up res since i will use the internal, 100nF would be ok for the cap? thanks for the answer to the point 1 and 2. I will have a read to the AN2867 to see how to correctly connect the crystals

Comment: edit: or should i put the 1k resistor between the switch and ground?

Comment: As @Conner mentioned above, the series resistor is an insurance policy to protect from a poorly configured pin (input vs output).  It is good practice to use them.  It is also a good idea to be aware of what the pins do when you are not in control (like during boot or a system hang/reset).  Do I always include them?  Well, no.  But I certainly do during prototyping.  The cap is a feel-good measure that *may* help with rejecting transients, but is largely ineffective for general DIO.  With proper switch de-bouncing code in software (or another hardware solution), the cap is  not necessary.

Comment: I am sorry to be so silly, but I will be the only one who will use this board so i don't need to make it robust under bonehead users (except me), could you tell me if it is ok and explain why and how that 1k R could prevent the MCU pin from broking if set as output? https://s4.postimg.org/v958ubual/Immagine.jpg @ChrisKnudsen Connor Wolf

Comment: @VincenzoGibiino - Ok. Assume the output is set to high (Vcc), now, what happens if you press the button? You short a driven MCU pin to ground.

Comment: ok I misunderstood and i thought that the 1k R could protect anyway the pin even if it was set to high. But using something like this: https://s14.postimg.org/7x8n5ript/Immagine.jpg the problem remains, or not? if it is set to high and i press the button i will short it anyway

Comment: @VincenzoGibiino Yes the 1k R will help.  with the mcu pin set to output-high (3.3v), and the R connected to Gnd, the mcu pin is protected from the short circuit to gnd.  The resistor will limit the current to 3.3/1000 (3.3 mA), which many mcu pins can handle without a problem.  If the R was not installed (0-ohms), then if the output pin was shorted to Gnd (or 3.3), then the pin output may be destroyed by the short because the output current is no longer limited.  The port pin could heat-up, and die a glorious death until its dead.  Same is true if the pin was set to output-low, and con to 3V.

Comment: thank you very much @ChrisKnudsen your answer helped me a lot and now it is clear why I should put it :D